# Proof $|x+y|+|x-y| \geq |x| + |y|$

Tags: analysis, inequality, absolute-value

Proof that for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$:
$$|x+y|+|x-y| \geq |x| + |y|$$

My (failed) attempt:
$$|x + y| \leq |x| + |y|$$
$$|x - y| \leq |x| + |y|$$
$$|x + y|+|x - y| \leq 2(|x| + |y|)$$

Thank you

Comment: Put $x=a[x[$, $y=b|y|$, with $a,b\in \{-1,1\}$. We have trivially that
$|x|+|y|\leq ||x|+|y||+||x|-|y||$, and replacing $|x|$ by $ax$ and $y$ by $by$, we get
$$||x|+|y||+||x|-|y||=|ax+by|+|ax-by|=|x+aby|+|x-aby|=[x+y|+|x-y|$$

Comment: @MartinR
I have been searching for a post like this but couln't find it. Sorry. Thanks for linking this! Your linked question contains [another very neat answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/986134/459435).

Comment: @Pagenotfound: I found it with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%7Cx%2By%7C%2B%7Cx-y%7C%20%5Cgeq%20%7Cx%7C%20%2B%20%7Cy%7C%24&p=1)

Comment: @MartinR
I think this search engine will change my life. Very useful! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $|a|+|b|\geqslant |a\pm b|$, so we have
$$
\Big|\frac{x+y}{2}\Big|+\Big|\frac{x-y}{2}\Big|\geqslant \Big|\frac{x+y}{2}+\frac{x-y}{2}\Big|=|x|.
$$
Similarly,
$$
\Big|\frac{x+y}{2}\Big|+\Big|\frac{x-y}{2}\Big|\geqslant \Big|\frac{x+y}{2}-\frac{x-y}{2}\Big|=|y|.
$$
Add them up, we get the desired inequality.

Comment: I was thinking about this problem for multiple hours and could not come up with a solution. I really like your proof because it looks so simple and does not involve squares. Excellent answer!

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*: break up the problem into four cases (when each of $x,y$ is positive or negative).

Comment: I did this but it felt so dirty that I was looking for a real proof. But thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

We have,
$$\color{red}{(|x+y|+|x-y|)^2 = 2(x^2+y^2) +2|x^2-y^2|}$$ Whence,

\begin{align}&2|x^2-y^2| \geq -x^2-y^2+2|x| |y|= -(|x|-|y|)^2\\
&\Longleftrightarrow(x^2+y^2) +2|x^2-y^2|\geq 2|x||y|\\
&\Longleftrightarrow 2(x^2+y^2) +2|x^2-y^2|\geq x^2+y^2+2|x||y|\\
&\Longleftrightarrow (|x+y|+|x-y|)^2 \geq (|x| + |y|)^2\\
&\Longleftrightarrow|x+y|+|x-y| \geq |x| + |y|
 \end{align}

Comment: Why did someone down vote this answer. ?

Answer (score 0):

squaring both sides we get
$$x^2+y^2+x^2+y^2+2|x+y||x-y|\geq x^2+y^2+2|x||y|$$ this is true since we have
$$(|x|-|y|)^2+2|x+y||x-y|\geq 0$$